# htaccess 301 Redirect not working from aspx to new WP permalink

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I'm fairly experienced with htaccess files and Rewrite/Redirect rules, however, this one has me stumped as to why it's not working.

**NONE** of the following lines (used individually, not together) have any effect. I simply get the normal 404 page when attempting the old URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule  ^carpetcare/default.aspx$ /carpet-care/ [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /carpetcare/default.aspx http://www.domain.com/carpet-care/
Redirect 301 /carpetcare/default.aspx /carpet-care/
```

The above lines all precede the typical WP htaccess rules here:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have other Rewrite rules that work perfectly, so it puzzles me why these simple redirects don't do *anything*.

Here is the entire htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule  ^carpetcare/default.aspx$ /carpet-care/ [R=301,L]
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/carpetcare/default.aspx$ /carpet-care/
Redirect 301 ^/carpetcare/default.aspx$ /carpet-care/


# Other rewrites
RewriteRule ^carpet-care/([-A-zA-Z]+)-cleaning(.*)/$ /loc.php?city=$1&cat=1 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress

# BEGIN wtwp_cache


    # Text
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType text/html .html .htm
    AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
    AddType text/plain .txt
    AddType text/xml .xml

    # Image
    AddType image/gif .gif
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
    AddType image/png .png
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz

    # Video
    AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
    AddType video/avi .avi
    AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe

    # PDF
    AddType application/pdf .pdf

    # Flash
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf

    # Font
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType application/x-font-otf .otf

    # Audio
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
    AddType audio/ogg .ogg
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/wma .wma

    # Zip/Tar
    AddType application/x-tar .tar
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
    AddType application/zip .zip



    ExpiresActive On

    # Text
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600

    # Image
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000

    # Video
    ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000

    # PDF
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000

    # Flash
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000

    # Font
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000

    # Audio
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000

    # Zip/Tar
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000


    
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
        Header unset ETag
    


    
        Header unset Set-Cookie
    

# END wtwp_cache

# BEGIN wtwp_security

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]


    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all

Options -Indexes
# END wtwp_security
```

Comment: Post that code as a whole, please, so that everything is in order-- order matters with `.htaccess`.

Comment: You are turning on the RewriteEngine in multiple places not sure if could cause issue but might be worth just doing it at the first set of rewrite rules.

Comment: Everything beginning at the initial "# BEGIN WordPress" line is verbatim from the WP install. I've only added lines above that. Notice that all "RewriteEngine On" statements are encapsulated in "If" blocks. Plus, my rewrite rule under "# Other rewrites" works perfectly.

Comment: See update above with full htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, and it's kinda boneheaded, but an easy mistake. I originally had the site running under a development domain (domain.info), then went live under a different domain (domain.com). I had FTP access to both domains, and it seemed while logging in using the ".info" domain was having an effect if I tried to purposely "break" the site (just to see if I was really using the right htaccess), I had to log in using the ".com" domain to get to the right one. I don't recall if these two sites are now living on separate hosting, but if that was true then I shouldn't be able to break the site by altering the "wrong" htaccess, right??

Anyhow, the basic redirect rule works just fine now.

```
Redirect 301 /carpetcare/default.aspx /carpet-care/
```

I spent WAY too long on this issue. ...arrgh!

Comment: Glad you solved it! Don't forget to come back and click the check mark to accept your answer :)